# Can't find the source of the gap at the top of my website. Double Checked all my tags

Tags: html, css

My html and body have margins and padding of 0. all my top level elements have the same.

I don't want to hack it with positon.. any tips? (ps I hacked the position up 33px. just in the meantime until i could find a solution that's less hacky.)

http://dextressband.com/landingpage.php

Comment: You need to provide more information than just a link to your website. Can you specify the element(s) you're having trouble positioning?

Comment: Sounds like there is content above the first visual tag, that is messing it up

Comment: Please do provide a sample of the problematic code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after your <title> tag, and in a few other places, you have this little problem:

[image: ZWNBSP in source]

This entity encodes U+FEFF, which is Unicode BOM. The entity is treated as text, and while it's completely invisible, it still reserves vertical space for itself before your div with main site content.

This usually means something is using a wrong encoding (UTF-8 with BOM where UTF-8 without BOM is expected) - since it's PHP, I'd start with locating the place where those sections of the site is rendered. If it's rendering the site from a file, check that the file is saved as UTF-8 without BOM in your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid.  Be sure the html is not producing this kind of "view source" in Firefox or other browsers that color code errors like this.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Okay, this will sound crazy, but you have a non-printable character in your head that is causing output to start.  Follow these directions carefully:

1. Put your cursor to the right of the "link" in your first stylesheet declaration (where i've put the asterisk...like this:)
2. Now use your backspace (or delete if you are on a Mac) and delete until you remove the HEAD tag so that the following tag is gone too
3. Now type  and hit enter and type

try loading your page again, because the demononic, non-printing character will be gone now and your html again valid.

**btw, for fun**

here is a picture of your non-printable character in my ViM session

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your html is missing an html element but you have an html 4.01 strict doctype

You have iframes but an html 4.01 strict doctype.